# Image size increases after upload it to Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded an image of size 7.4 MB to the firebase storage, but I got 24.8 MB. Why this happen? And how may I solve it?

**Notice: I did not create any changes in the size of the image, I kept it as it is.**

Here is the code:

```
    func storeImageInFirebase(){
           let storeageRef = Storage.storage().reference()  
           let imageName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
           let imagesReference = storeageRef.child("images").child(imageName)
           let imageData = self.imgView.image!.pngData()
           let metaData = StorageMetadata()


           metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
           imagesReference.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData){ (metadate, error)
               in
               guard metadate != nil else{
                   print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                   return
               }
              // Fetch the download URL
               imagesReference.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error)
                   in
                   if error != nil {
                       print("Faild to download url:", error!)
                       return
                   }else{
                       // show the url in real database


                   }
               })

           }

       }
```

Comment: Can you post the function you are using to upload the image to firebase?

Comment: try to use let imageData = self.imgView.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75), also use metada as nil,I means imagesReference.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil)

Comment: @luffy_064 why I need to write nil rather than metaData, Also, what the different between ```.pngData()``` and ```.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)```?

Comment: well when you are using metadata, you are adding some information to user image, and this increase the size, usually when you upload image its recomendable apply compress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. You can change maxCompression and maxFileSize to suit your needs. This will continue looping/compressing the file by increments of 0.05 while the image is bigger than your max size and while compression is higher than your max compression.

```
func storeImageInFirebase(image: UIImage) {
    var compression: CGFloat = 0.9 //starting compression
    let maxCompression: CGFloat = 0.05 //change to the maximum compression you want
    let maxFileSize: Int = 512 * 512 //change to the maximum file size you want
    guard var uploadImageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression) else {
        print("ERROR: Creating photo data")
        return
    }

    while (uploadImageData.count > maxFileSize) && (compression > maxCompression) {
        compression -= 0.05
        if let compressedImageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression) {
            uploadImageData = compressedImageData
        }
    }

    guard let uploadImageDataFinal = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression) else {
        print("ERROR: Compressing final photo")
        return
    }

    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(imageName)

    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    storageRef.putData(uploadImageDataFinal, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("ERROR: Adding photo to storage")
            return
        } else {
            //success
            print("SUCCESS: Photo uploaded")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

To download image add this function to the view controller:

```
func getImage(handler: @escaping(_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(imageName)
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 27 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            print("SUCCESS: downloaded image")
            handler(image)
        } else {
            print("ERROR downloading image. \(error)")
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

When you need to download the image use:

```
    self.getImage { (returnedImage) in
        if let image = returnedImage {
            //use image here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to download the image from Firebase Storage

Comment: Go into Firebase Storage, navigate to the uploaded image, and check the image name. Make sure it is exactly the same as the path your are downloading.

Comment: yes, it is the same and when I click to the url it is open the new tab in the browser unlike in my code it is auto downloaded

Comment: I added some code in the answer for an easy/safe way to download images. It's faster to use .getData than .downloadURL if you don't need a URL.

Comment: How to give an exact size of an uploaded image rather than constant ```let maxFileSize: Int = 512 * 512```?

Comment: The code will shrink the image down just below the file size you put in maxFileSize. It won't be the exact same for every picture but that shouldn't really matter.